# JSF: How to throw an exception from within a facelet

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.3

Is there a way to throw an exception from within a facelet? Background: I've a component using a customised converter as parameter. So I call the component as

```java
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomConverter implements Converter<String>
...
```

```html
...
<ui:param
  name="pConverter"
  value="#{customConverter}" />
...
```

But when there's a typo in the param value e.g.

```html
...
<ui:param
  name="pConverter"
  value="#{custoMConverter}" /> <!-- custoMConverter instead of customConverter -->
...
```

the converter is consequently not working but no exception is thrown. Now I would like to throw an exception from within the component if the converter is empty in such a case. How to do that?

Why is a non existent element not throwing an exception at all?

```html
<h:outputText value="#{fooBean.foo}" />
```

There's no exception if the bean `fooBean` doesn't exist. Why not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationBean {
    public final void checkExistenceAndThrow(final Object o) {
        if (Objects.isNull(o)) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the component check for the existence of the converter:

```html
<h:outputText
  value="#{applicationBean.checkExistenceAndThrow(pConverter)}"
  style="display: none;" />
```

So the throwing of the exception is delegated to the bean.